# AutoMapper how to flatten nested lists

Tags: automapper

I am trying to map out some nested lists into a list of flattened structures using automapper.
Currently I am able to map the correct number of credits with names but I can not get the role and role description to map across.

I am trying to get a flattened list like this.

John Smith, Actor, Dr Evil

John Smith, Writer, null

Frank Brown, Director, null

Joe Green, Actor, Henchman

Here is a cutdown version of my domain model, view model and mapping.
What am I doing wrong with the Domain.Credit to ViewModel.Credit mapping?

```
//Domain Model
public class Talent
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Credit> Credits { get; set; }
}

public class Credit
{
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subtitle { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }        
}

//View Model
public class EpisodeViewModel
{
    public IList<Credit> Credits { get; set; }

    public class Credit
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
        public string RoleDescription { get; set; }
    }
}

//Mappings
Mapper.CreateMap<Episode, EpisodeViewModel>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Credits, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Talent));

Mapper.CreateMap<Talent, Credit>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Name, options => options.MapFrom(source => string.Format("{0} {1}", source.FirstName, source.LastName)));

Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Credit, Credit>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Role, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Role.Title))
    .ForMember(destination => destination.RoleDescription, options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Subtitle));
```

Comment: I think this is similar to a problem I had a while back. Take a look at [this answer on the automapper mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/automapper-users/b66c1M8eS8E) to see if it helps resolve your issue. If it does, I'll copy it in here for future reference.